# jsonb with psycopg2 RealDictCursor

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2, postgresql-9.4

I have a postgresql 9.4 (aka mongodb killer ;-) ) and this simple schema :

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL, name text, misc jsonb);
```

now i populate this, if i make a select it will show something like

```
id    |     name      |    misc
1     |     user1     | { "age" : 23, "size" : "M" }
2     |     user2     | { "age" : 30, "size" : "XL" }
```

now, if i make a request with psycopg2,

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
rows = list(cur)
```

i'll end up with

```
[ { 'id' : 1, 'name' : 'user1', 'misc' : '{ "age" : 23, "size" : "M" }' }, 
{ 'id2' : 2, 'name' : 'user2', 'misc' : '{ "age" : 30, "size" : "XL' }' }]
```

what's wrong you would tell me ? well misc is type str. i would expect it to be recognized as json and converted as Python dict.

from psycopg2 doc ([psycopg2/extras page](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html)) it states that "Reading from the database, json values will be automatically converted to Python objects."

with RealDictCursor it seems that it is not the case.
it means that that i cannot access rows[0]['misc']['age'] as it would be convenient...

ok, i could do manually with

```
for r in rows:
    r['misc'] = json.loads(r['misc'])
```

but if i can avoid that because there's a nicer solution...

ps.
someone with 1500+ rep could create the postgresql9.4 tag ;-)

Comment: It looks like `psycopg2` just doesn't understand that `jsonb` is also a json type, yet. Are you on the very latest psycopg2? If so, you might need to add a type handler - see the psycopg2 docs for how - until it has native support.

Comment: What happens if it is cast to `json`? `select id, name, misc::json from test;`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, good idea: it works casting to json and psycopg2 returns misc as 'dict' as expected ! thx

Comment: @CraigRinger, using 2.5.3 which is current python3-psycopg2 on Debian testing. Yop i saw it in docs but i suspected it was more usefull for INSERT (to tell to convert dict to json) but i may be wrong on my understanding.

Comment: Additionnal test : it's weird, if i cast to json my request : SELECT id, name, misc::json FROM test; it's fine... but if i cast to jsonb : SELECT id, name, misc::jsonb FROM test; it's no good, i end with misc returned as str() as before. not very logic IMHO.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. `psycopg2` recognises the `json` type but not yet the `jsonb` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current psycopg version (2.5.3) doesn't know the oid for the jsonb type. In order to support it it's enough to call:

```
import psycopg2.extras
psycopg2.extras.register_json(oid=3802, array_oid=3807, globally=True)
```

once in your project.

You can find further information in [this ML message](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+mi_8bd_g-MDPMwa88w0HXfjysaLFcrCza90+KL9zpRGbxKWg@mail.gmail.com).

Comment: Note: transparent jsonb support should be added in psycopg 2.5.4, before PostgreSQL 9.4 release.

Answer (score 1):

Works out of the box with psycopg2 2.7.1 (not need to json.loads -- dictionaries are what come out of queries.)

```
  sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
  sudo pip install psycopg2 --upgrade
  python -c "import psycopg2 ; print psycopg2.__version__"

  2.7.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
```